# Custom value for RangeTickLabel AndroidPlot

Tags: android, androidplot

I am using LineChart for plotting realtime data. I need to display custom value for the Range Tick labels. For example if the Range value is 600, I need to display it as 6mv. Could someone please suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the conversion you want to use is simply value / 100:

```
plot.setRangeValueFormat(new Format() {
    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Object object, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition field) {
        Number value = (Number) object;
            buffer.append(value.doubleValue() / 100 + "mv");
                return buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseObject(String string, ParsePosition position) {
        return null;
    }
});
```